# Combining for and if loops

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x

I have the code:

```
num_for_loops = 0
for line in lines:
    if line.strip().startswith('for '):
        num_for_loops += 1
return num_for_loops
```

I need to condense it down to as little lines as possible. Is there a way to do this by combining the for and if statements?
The context is irrelevant.

Comment: "I need to condense it down to as little lines as possible"? ***Why***? The context *is* relevant.

Comment: Micro-optimization: you are checking just the beginning of each line (`.startswith('for ')`), so you could replace `strip()` with `lstrip()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
num_for_loops = sum(line.strip().startswith("for ") for line in lines)
```

since you're immediately returning `num_for_loops` I suppose you really just want

```
return sum(line.strip().startswith("for ") for line in lines)
```

Comment: Interesting cast of `True` and `False` to 1 and 0. :-)

Comment: Thanks exactly what I wanted to know

Answer (score 3):

Generator expressions always win concise code contests:

```
return sum(1 for line in lines if line.strip().startswith('for '))
```

That generates a series of 1s equal in length to the number of lines starting with 'for ', summing the list as it's generated so that you could parse terabytes of data without running out of memory.